# How to deploy .war from s3 to elasticbeanstalk using AWS CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-cli

I'm using `aws cli` (not eb `cli`).
I have copied a `.war` to my s3 bucket:

```
aws s3 cp app-${VERSION}.war s3://elasticbeanstalk-xxx/sub/app-${VERSION}.war
```

Now I have for example: `app-1.0.0.war` on my S3. But now I'm stuck. 
I have an elastic beanstalk application named `superapp`. I have 2 environments `superapp-dev` and `superapp-uat`.

Now I try to use something like this:

```
aws elasticbeanstalk update-environment --application-name superapp --environment-name superapp-dev --version-label 1.0.0'
```

But this does not work. 
I assume I first have to add a the version to my .war and after that I can update my environment?

Can someone help me to explain what step(s) I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

After upload your file to S3, you must create the "label" on Elastic Beanstalk side with a call to create-application-version.

In your case :

```
aws elasticbeanstalk create-application-version --application-name superapp --version-label 1.0.0 --source-bundle S3Bucket=elasticbeanstalk-xxx,S3Key=sub/app-1.0.0.war
```

See complete reference here for more optional parameters: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/elasticbeanstalk/create-application-version.html

After that, you will be able to do your update-environment.